# Mute button turns off sound but not back on?

Tags: c#

I have a function that plays sound that looks like this.

```
void PlaySound()
{
    if (!mute)
    {
        Sound stuff here
    }
}
```

Then I have a function that handles the mute button being pressed which does this.

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{
    if (mute == true) { mute = false; }
    if (mute == false) { mute = true; }
}
```

This script will turn the sound off when pressed, but will not turn it back on if I press it again. I've tried using !mute instead of mute == false and that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "That didn't work" isn't the best explanation. Please be more specific, show what exactly isn't working and add the actual Error/Exception to your post

Comment: First of all, your if statement logic in `MuteButtonPressed()` is all wrong, there is no else condition, what do you think is going to happen?  Also, you dont need all that code in there anyway, just make the method body simply: `mute = !mute;`. Next, what is the actual problem you are having?  Its not playing sounds?  Have you debugged to see if `mute` has the value expected when you try to do your "sound stuff"?

Comment: Read the steps/logic of `MuteButtonPressed` and consider what happens when mute is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your problem is you are using two `if` statements instead of an `if/else` statement.

Consider your logic if `mute` is true:

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{
    if (mute == true) 
    { 
        mute = false; //mute is true so make it false
    } 
    if (mute == false) //We just set mute to false so now this triggers
    { 
        mute = true; //setting mute to true again
    } 
}
```

With your logic, effectively nothing changes after running this method.  To fix that, use an `if/else` statement.  Two `if` statements will run after another, an `if/else` statement will only run *one* of the blocks:

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{        
    if (mute) //if mute is true run the if block
    { 
        mute = false; 
    } 
    else //if mute is false run the else block
    { 
        mute = true; 
    } 
}
```

Or way more simply:

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{
    mute = !mute; //make mute equal to the opposite of mute (i.e flip the switch)
}
```

I also strongly recommend reading up on proper formatting.  Having your if statements inline like you were doing is very hard to read and debug.

Comment: Much better than the strange if/return situation... Easier to read too. Whitespace and formatting are our friends.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i describe your error: you have written

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{
    if (mute == true) { mute = false; } // if mute == true then mute = false
    if (mute == false) { mute = true; } // the process continue so mute = true
}
```

to avoid that you have to add return like this:

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{
    if (mute == true) { mute = false; return;} 
    if (mute == false) { mute = true; }
}
```

but this solution is better:

```
public void MuteButtonPressed()
{
    mute = !mute;
}
```

Comment: You missed the `;` on the `return` and `mute = !mute`.

Comment: `"to avoid that you have to add return like this:"` -- or just use an `if/else` instead of `if/if`

Comment: I'd also recommend demonstrating some better formatting practices as well. An if condition and 2 additional statements *plus* curly braces makes my eyes water.